# Emacs find-file-other-window command splits buffer vertically

Tags: emacs, window

I am just setting up Emacs on a new machine and I am running into trouble with the command `find-file-other-window`. The way I typically like to work is with the frame split horizontally into two windows. I'd like to be able to run said command and have it open the file in the other window, but instead most of the time it splits the current window into 2 new windows horizontally. How do I get it to stop doing this? Thanks.

EDIT: Also want to point out that this only happens when I scale the frame to a large enough size.

Comment: can't replicate. `Mx-find-file-other-window` opens a file in a new window if there's ony one, In the adjacent window if there are two or more. It doesn't split into a new window. What system and version are you using?

Comment: In the window where you wanted the file/buffer displayed, but it didn't happen there, you may want to try evaluating `(window-dedicated-p)` to see if it is dedicated.  If it is dedicated, then display-buffer family of functions will try to preserve that dedication.  After doing all that, you can make a decision whether to prevent that window from being dedicated in the future or look for ways to override the dedication.

Comment: @manandearth Emacs 26.1, High Sierra.

Answer (score 2):

Normally this action is performed by the function
`split-window-sensibly`, and controlled by two variables,
`split-height-threshold` and `split-width-threshold`. Per the
documentation

> If ‘split-height-threshold’ specifies an integer, WINDOW is at least
>   ‘split-height-threshold’ lines tall and can be split vertically, split
>   WINDOW into two windows one above the other and return the lower
>   window.  Otherwise, if ‘split-width-threshold’ specifies an integer,
>   WINDOW is at least ‘split-width-threshold’ columns wide and can be
>   split horizontally, split WINDOW into two windows side by side and
>   return the window on the right.  If this can’t be done either and
>   WINDOW is the only window on its frame, try to split WINDOW vertically
>   disregarding any value specified by ‘split-height-threshold’.  If that
>   succeeds, return the lower window.  Return nil otherwise.

On my system the default value for `split-height-threshold` is 80 and `split-width-threshold` is 160. I think you could get the effect you want by setting `split-width-threshold` to something lower. Alternatively you could set `split-height-threshold` to nil, preventing it from ever splitting vertically, or set the variable `split-window-preferred-function` to a different function. Any of these would affect, not just `find-file-in-other-window`, but all the functions that split the screen.